# vagrant composer install feedback

Tags: php, vagrant, composer-php

So I have a vagrant setup that installs composer packages, but when I do `vagrant up` and it reaches the `composer install` stage it just hangs, what is happening is that one of the composer packages is requiring feedback, I believe it's PHPUnit and it wants a key from github to install, but vagrant isn't showing me the feedback or allowing me to enter the code. How can I do this with vagrant? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got your access token from github I believe you can preinstall the key for composer if you cd into the directory where the composer.json file is and run the following command.

```
composer config github-oauth.github.com YOUR-TOKEN-HASH-GOES-HERE
```

You'd put that in the bootstrap.sh file just before it runs composer install.

[Here's a link](https://coderwall.com/p/kz4egw/composer-install-github-rate-limiting-work-around) to where I found out about this. Hope that helps.